# What is the proper way to reference transform variable in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```cs
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
  transfrom.Translate(0, 0, 1);
}
```

I get an error saying:

> Assets\Course Library\Scripts\PlayerCotroller.cs(16,7): error CS0103: The name 'transfrom' does not exist in the current context

What is the proper way to reference this variable further down the page?

Comment: generally by using the correct name ;) `transfrom` != `transform`

Answer (score 2):

Typo, `transfrom` should be written as `transform`

```cs
// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
  transform. Translate(0, 0, 1);
}
```

Comment: [Should you answer questions where the cause of the problem is a typo?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/366135/should-you-answer-questions-where-the-cause-of-the-problem-is-a-typo)